# Get build ID from artifactory URL in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, build-automation

I have a Jenkins setup that generates a tar archive periodically and pushes it to the artifactory.
I want to be able to fetch the details of the jenkins job, given any artifactory build URL. 
Is there any REST API that accepts the artifactory build URL and returns the job information/metadata?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may produce a file containing the job information and put it into tar archive that you're pushing.

Comment: Yes, but I'd then have to download the entire archive to find that information. That is not possible for me

Comment: Then you can implement the functionality where you send the jenkins job details together with the URL and fetch it later by URL. We use `consul` for something similar, but Redis might meet your requirements, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the URL either, as this artifactory is accessible by customers and they don't need to know the jenkins job details.

Comment: Check https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties